# I have the following error. How to fix the following certificate error (ipython)?

Tags: certificate, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error when I want to run ipython notebook on my macbook. Does anyone know how to fix this? Could you please help me about it?

```
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 346, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 167, in accept_handler
    callback(connection, address)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 217, in _handle_connection
    do_handshake_on_connect=False)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 407, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return ssl.wrap_socket(socket, **dict(context, **kwargs))
  File "//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 141, in __init__
    ciphers)
SSLError: [Errno 336445449] _ssl.c:368: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 346, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 167, in accept_handler
    callback(connection, address)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 217, in _handle_connection
    do_handshake_on_connect=False)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 407, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return ssl.wrap_socket(socket, **dict(context, **kwargs))
  File "//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 141, in __init__
    ciphers)
SSLError: [Errno 336445449] _ssl.c:368: error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears that your browser is attempting to access the notebook without SSL. Make sure to access the site with HTTPS. For example, when you access the notebook, type in `https://127.0.0.1:9999` in your browser. (Or whatever the address of the server is.)

Comment: Chrome and Google for instance will give the "This connection is not private" message and your have to click on "advanced" and then proceed anyway to get to the ipython server

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't recognise the files you're passing it - either:

1. pass a .pem file (private key) to `--NotebookApp.keyfile=` and the .crt file (your certificate) to `--NotebookApp.certfile=`
2. create a new file by appending your certificate to your key and pass this new file to `--certfile`.