# IPython notebook start issues

Tags: python, ipython

I am facing the following exception while running IPython Notebook on Windows 7. It seems to be an installation issue.

```
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 644
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 340, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 644
```

Comment: possibly related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146662/i-have-the-following-error-how-to-fix-the-following-certificate-error-ipython/23603935#23603935

Comment: 1. If you have a Desktop with no application open, what do you do to create this error? 2. What have you installed?

Comment: I installed ipython and run following command from command prompt:
ipython notebook

Comment: @Korem: How do I create openssl pem files? Is it mandatory?

Comment: @user3855919 sry, no clue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after I attempted to install ipython-sql on my windows box:
I upgraded my ipython from an multi-year old pythonxy version ( as found in pythonxy 2.7.3.1) to the most recent version downloaded from the ipython website: ipython-2.1.0.
I re-installed manually a lot of the dependencies of ipython (in chronological order) and re-installed (python setup.py install) ipython between each of these

```
ipython_sql-0.3.1-py2.7.egg
sqlparse-0.1.11.tar.gz
prettytable-0.7.2.zip
tornado-4.0.tar.gz
backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2.tar.gz
certifi-14.05.14.tar.gz
pyzmq-14.3.1-py2.7-win32.egg
```

It is the upgrade of pyzmq which seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: "It is the upgrade of pyzmq which seems to have solved the problem."

This fixed it for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I've updated old pyzmq version by
`pip install --upgrade pyzmq`
and it has worked for me well.